# What is the purpose of org.eclipse.jst.ws.util.JspUtils.markup(String text) method

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services

I am checking out previous implemented application for `web services` where the `request` and `response` objects are instance of classes generated by `.wsdl` file.

I go through the code and found this line after getting `response` objects

```
 String someVariable=org.eclipse.jst.ws.util.JspUtils.markup(String.valueOf(response.getSomeVariable()));
```

I tried to find out what is the use of this method `org.eclipse.jst.ws.util.JspUtils.markup(String text)` but I could not find something clear on the internet.

I found this **[Method implementation](http://eclipsesrc.appspot.com/jsrcs/org.eclipse.jst.ws.consumption/webserviceutils/org/eclipse/jst/ws/util/JspUtils.java.html)** but I still did not understand the purpose of this method in the `web services`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method obviously takes a string and escape those characters that have a special meaning in XML and HTML.

Example:

`val <= 1.5` would be converted to `val &lt;= 1.5`